# How to Get JSON String for header/payload from JWT token using java-jwt

Tags: java, jwt

Is there a method in java-jwt that will return the token as a single JSON string (or at least the header and payload as two JSON strings)? Does JJWT support this?

Looking at the tutorial at https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt I'm not seeing this method (there are individual getters for individual pieces of the message but I'm not seeing anything that returns the complete message as a JSON string).

The getHeader() and getHeader() methods return the encoded strings.  I'm trying to get the headers and payload as JSON (similar to what is shown at https://jwt.io/).  How do I do this?

Here's the code so far:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

public class CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateToken() {
        logger.info("Starting test...");
        // create the token
        String key = "foobarkey";
        Algorithm alg = Algorithm.HMAC256(key);
        String issuer = "me";
        JWTCreator.Builder jwt = JWT.create();
        jwt.withIssuer(issuer);
        jwt.withClaim("createdBy", "CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest");
        jwt.withClaim("purpose", "test");
        jwt.withClaim("msg", "Hello World.");
        String token = jwt.sign(alg);
        logger.info("Created token: \n" + token);
        // read the token
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(alg)
                .withIssuer(issuer)
                .build();
        DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);
        logger.info("Header: \n" + decoded.getHeader());
        logger.info("Payload: \n" + decoded.getPayload());
        logger.info("Done.");
    }

}
```

And here's the output:

```
2020-05-19 08:23:31,387 08:23:31.387 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:19) - Starting test...
2020-05-19 08:23:32,226 08:23:32.226 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:30) - Created token: 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtc2ciOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZC4iLCJjcmVhdGVkQnkiOiJDcmVhdGVUb2tlbkV4YW1wbGVJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblRlc3QiLCJwdXJwb3NlIjoidGVzdCIsImlzcyI6Im1lIn0.VmYsToj1PKBzJKQuXEyiKuJA-GkNVit0Ylh44dVF2UI
2020-05-19 08:23:32,273 08:23:32.273 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:36) - Header: 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
2020-05-19 08:23:32,273 08:23:32.273 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:37) - Payload: 
eyJtc2ciOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZC4iLCJjcmVhdGVkQnkiOiJDcmVhdGVUb2tlbkV4YW1wbGVJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblRlc3QiLCJwdXJwb3NlIjoidGVzdCIsImlzcyI6Im1lIn0
2020-05-19 08:23:32,273 08:23:32.273 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:38) - Done.
```

### EDIT: This is a complete solution based on the accepted answer:

#### Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

public class CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateToken() {
        logger.info("Starting test...");
        // create the token
        String key = "foobarkey";
        Algorithm alg = Algorithm.HMAC256(key);
        String issuer = "me";
        JWTCreator.Builder jwt = JWT.create();
        jwt.withIssuer(issuer);
        jwt.withClaim("createdBy", "CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest");
        jwt.withClaim("purpose", "test");
        jwt.withClaim("msg", "Hello World.");
        String token = jwt.sign(alg);
        logger.info("Created token: \n" + token);
        // read the token
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(alg)
                .withIssuer(issuer)
                .build();
        DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);
        // header
        String encHeader = decoded.getHeader();
        String header = decode(encHeader);
        logger.info("Header: \n" + encHeader + "\n" + header);
        // payload
        String encPayload = decoded.getPayload();
        String payload = decode(encPayload);
        logger.info("Payload: \n" + encPayload + "\n" + payload);
        // done
        logger.info("Done.");
    }

    public String decode(final String base64) {
        return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(base64));
    }

}
```

#### Output:

```
2020-05-19 10:13:29,146 10:13:29.146 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:21) - Starting test...
2020-05-19 10:13:30,031 10:13:30.031 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:32) - Created token: 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtc2ciOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZC4iLCJjcmVhdGVkQnkiOiJDcmVhdGVUb2tlbkV4YW1wbGVJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblRlc3QiLCJwdXJwb3NlIjoidGVzdCIsImlzcyI6Im1lIn0.VmYsToj1PKBzJKQuXEyiKuJA-GkNVit0Ylh44dVF2UI
2020-05-19 10:13:30,102 10:13:30.102 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:41) - Header: 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}
2020-05-19 10:13:30,103 10:13:30.103 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:45) - Payload: 
eyJtc2ciOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZC4iLCJjcmVhdGVkQnkiOiJDcmVhdGVUb2tlbkV4YW1wbGVJbnRlZ3JhdGlvblRlc3QiLCJwdXJwb3NlIjoidGVzdCIsImlzcyI6Im1lIn0
{"msg":"Hello World.","createdBy":"CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest","purpose":"test","iss":"me"}
2020-05-19 10:13:30,103 10:13:30.103 [main] INFO  (CreateTokenExampleIntegrationTest.java:47) - Done.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through `java-jwt` and I don't think that it outputs the `payload` and `header` JSON Strings other than `base64-encoded`. Also, the "normal" JSON strings are just temporary local Strings in the cunstructor of `JWTDecoder` (see [here](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/blob/d89d746c1a10c128d257a3ef6187bd72937cc0c8/lib/src/main/java/com/auth0/jwt/JWTDecoder.java#L38)) and private inaccessible fields of `JWTCreator` (see [here](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/blob/a81f3076ee02d5bfa305597b5d2aa2341c2657a8/lib/src/main/java/com/auth0/jwt/JWTCreator.java#L29)) which never get "exposed to the public".

So you either have to decode the `base64` Strings yourself or access the private Fields of `JWTCreator` via Reflections. But I'd definitely choose decoding the String manually in this case. That could look like this (equal with how `JWTDecoder` [does it](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/blob/d89d746c1a10c128d257a3ef6187bd72937cc0c8/lib/src/main/java/com/auth0/jwt/JWTDecoder.java#L38)):

```
public String decodeToJson(final String base64){
        return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(base64));
}
```

```
DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token); // in your Test-Class

final String headerJson = decodeToJson(decoded.getHeader());
final String payloadJson = decodeToJson(decoded.getPayload());
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks! I added this as an edit in the original question.